# insert an id gotten from another table

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a message table

```
**message**
---------------------------------------
msg_id (AI) | user_id | content
```

and user table

```
**user**
---------------------------------------
user_id (AI) | email | password | name
```

I would like to store the user who posted the message into the database. The codes I have written allows me to store the message submitted into the database but not the `user_id`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
        $msg = new msg();
        $msg->user_id = ???
        $msg->content = trim($_POST['content']);
        if ($msg->createMsg()) {
            //action
        } else {
            //action
        }
```

the `createMsg()` is a sql statement that inserts my query.

how do I get the `user_id` from the `user` table to store into the `message` table?

Comment: How do you keep track of the current logged in user?

Comment: @Blaatpraat using session

Comment: u can take user_id from session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store user data during login into session like `$_SESSION['user'];`

```
$msg->user_id = $_SESSION['user']['user_id'];
```